# Angular - Module not available

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, meanjs

I am using mean.js boilerplate. I would like to include [angular-stripe](https://github.com/bendrucker/angular-stripe) in my client side. For that I have installed angular-stripe and it is available under node_modules.

Now I would like to add it in my code as follows

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
  .module('myApp', [
    'angular-stripe'
  ])
  .config(function (stripeProvider) {
    stripeProvider.setPublishableKey('my_key')
  })

      PaymentController.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', 'Authentication', 'Socket', 'stripe'];

      function PaymentController($scope, $state, Authentication, Socket, stripe) {
        var vm = this; 
    }
());
```

It throws the folowing error

```
Module 'angular-stripe' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Comment: Did you include the angular-stripe plugin before your main app.js loads?

Comment: dear first check you have include plugin angular-stripe and .js file in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MeanJs boilerplate, you have to add your dependencies at `config/assets/default.js` in `client - lib` and `client-css` if the dependecy has a `.css` file.

```
module.exports = {
  client: {
    lib: {
      css: [
        // bower:css
        'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
        'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css',
        'public/lib/angular-ui-notification/dist/angular-ui-notification.css'
        // endbower
      ],
      js: [
        // bower:js
        'node_modules/angular-stripe/src/index.js',
        'public/lib/angular/angular.js',
        'public/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
        'public/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
        'public/lib/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.js',
        'public/lib/angular-messages/angular-messages.js',
        'public/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'public/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
        'public/lib/angular-ui-notification/dist/angular-ui-notification.js',
        'public/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
        'public/lib/owasp-password-strength-test/owasp-password-strength-test.js',
        // endbower
      ], // rest of the code..
```

MeanJs highly recommend to use `bower` for your frontend dependencies.
For more info: [MeanJS docs](http://meanjs.org/docs)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the *angular-stripe* plugin is not included when the angular module is declared.

When using js modules from node_modules, use the global require() method in your module declaration instead

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  require('angular-stripe')
]);
```

The other solution is to include the files the "standard" way `<script src="...`.

Good blog post about the require method [here](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm)